# Android Studio - Junit 4 - Running code before ALL tests

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, junit4

I have an app to which I want to force the `locale` whenever the app is opened. So I will use `Locale.setDefault(myCountryLocale).` in the application's `onCreate()` method

Unit Tests don't start that class, so I want to be able to set the same locale whenever tests are started. Either by an extension or gradle script to setup the locale so that tests don't fail if whoever runs them uses another locale.

Comment: is your problem solved? If yes, could you please tell me how?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kinda old post but I faced this problem.
You can extends `RunListener` class and override the `testRunStarted` this code block will run only once before all your tests.
This listener will be added to you test manifest like this

```
<instrumentation
    android:name="androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    android:targetPackage="YOUR_APP_PACKAGE">
    <meta-data
        android:name="listener"
        android:value="YOUR_LISTENER_PACKAGE" />
</instrumentation>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try and get back with an approve if it works :P

Comment: Hey @htafoya was the above solution helpful ?

Comment: @HazemWahed It works with instrumentation tests. Do we have something similar for unit tests also?